# Double integral with indicator function in Matlab (or R)?

Tags: matlab, integral, indicator

I need to calculate this double integral:

[image]

where f(x) and f(y) are the density of the distribution of r.v a and y (they are distributed as normal and are independent each other)

with Matlab. I've tried this

I've tried this:

```
fun = @(x,y)((5-2*y)/3)*((1./sqrt(4*pi))*exp(-(x-2)^(2)/4))*((1./sqrt(8*pi))*exp(-(x-1)^(2)/8))
xmax = @(y)(5-2*y)/3
q = integral2(fun,-Inf,1,1,xmax)
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? (I'm not a Matlab expert). If not Matlab, with R it's ok.

Comment: Please actually post your code as text.  Don't upload an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `fun` does not allow vectorized inputs, which means evaluating multiple inputs at once. Try for example:

```
fun([1,2],[3,4])
```

The expected output would be

```
[fun(1,3),fun(2,4)]
```

To fix this, you have to use the elementwise operations, which is already suggested to you via the error message:

> Error using  ^ 
>   Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
>   **To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^)
>   instead.**

Comment: Thank you..I have no idea on how to use elementwise operations in this case

Comment: `^` is the wrong operation, you have to replace it with `.^`